# AnyOne know why i keep getting This error when i try to set state on load

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, onload

I keep getting this error I'm trying to display none the image until it has loaded but I get React Limits the number of renders to prevent infinite loop. If you know a better way of doing this please let me know. I want the image to not display the ...loading image while loading it is very ugly and it ony happens on Mobile Im using .Png File should i convert to svg so it loads faster?

```
        Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
        ▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
        Spinner
        C:/Users/Test/Documents/GitHub/Ecommerce-Store/src/components/Spinner.jsx:26
        23 | return (
        24 |   <div style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
        25 |     <img
        > 26 |       onLoad={setloaded('true')}
            | ^  27 |       id="preloader"
        28 |       src={preloader}
        29 |       alt="loading..."

        import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
        import { isAndroid, isIOS } from 'react-device-detect';
        import android from '../spinners/androidlogo.png';
        import apple from '../spinners/Applelogo.png';
        import spinner from '../spinners/VHUBLogospin.gif';

        const Spinner = props => {
        const [preloader, setpreloader] = useState(null);
        const [loaded, setloaded] = useState(false)
        // const productConsumer = useContext(ProductContext);
        // // const { showSpinner } = productConsumer;
        useEffect(() => {
            if (isIOS) {
            setpreloader(apple);
            } else if (isAndroid) {
            setpreloader(android);
            } else {
            setpreloader(spinner);
            }
            // showSpinner(preloader);
        }, []);

        return (
            <div style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
            <img
                onLoad={setloaded('true')}
                id="preloader"
                src={preloader}
                alt="loading..."
                style={{
                width: '200px',
                margin: 'auto',
                display: 'block',
                marginTop: '3%',
                paddingTop: '25vh',

                }}
                className={!loaded ? 'display-none' : '' }
            />
            </div>
        );
        };

        export default Spinner;
```

Comment: That is because you are setting the state on load `onLoad={setloaded('true')`. every time a change in state, the DOM will rerender and again on load, it will try to set state and again DOM will rerender. Therefore it will go into an infinite loop. You may remove  `onLoad={setloaded('true')` and try some other logic to get rid of this infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `onLoad={() => {setloaded('true')}}`

Comment: Had to add !important to my css display property it now works

Comment: Thanks I have one more question if you can help. How do i export multiple exponents withRouter? export  withRouter{ Navbar, MobileMenu };

Comment: I didn't get your question completely. You can try something like
```
exports = {
Navbar: withRouter(Navbar),
MobileMenu: withRouter(MobileMenu)
};
```

Comment: Let me see if i can post another question yet one sec

Comment: I am trying to export both of these exponents withrouter so i can use props.location.

                  export withrouter?? { Navbar, MobileMenu };

Comment: Want to export both of these with router

Comment: you can use like thie `module.exports = { Navbar: withRouter(Navbar), MobileMenu: withRouter(MobileMenu) };` and when you use it in other place you have to do `import { Navbar, MobileMenu } from "path-to-the-file"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197852/discussion-between-thegreen-lightbulb-and-aditya).